# bootstrap label "for" attribute use?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I know how to use label.
I know that the `For` attribute should have Id of the input.
Also I know there is another way to link the label to an input by wrapping it around the input like this:

```
<label>test <input type="text" /></label>
```

What I couldn't figure out is why in bootstrap,there is no Id  for the textarea and the label tag is assigned to word "name" as follow:

```
<label for="name" > test </label>
<textarea class=form-control" rows="3" ></textarea >
```

Comment: Where did you saw that?

Comment: Bootstrap is just a CSS framework, it doesn't add any HTML magic. The some HTML is valid or invalid, no matter if you use bootstrap or not. So either someone forgot the `name` element (and thus has invalid HTML) or it is somewhere else in the markup.

Comment: @Miljan I saw it herehttp://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/index.htm?utm_source=tuicool in the pdf page 45

Comment: So all responses here suggest that it's typo error??

Comment: Yeah, he's forgot id="name" for textarea. He can add it later with JS or jQuery, but without it - it's not valid and click on that label will not focus textarea (again, he can add click event with jQuery, but that is not the point).